# Make lucene string field range searchable

Tags: java, lucene

I'm new with Lucene and am having some issues with making a string field searchable within a range.

So, I have a document that consists of a couple of string fields. One of which is a version which ca have the forms

1.0, 1.1, 1.0-RC1... i.e. Major.Minor(-RCX)

The version strings have a backing java class (Version) which implements Comparable.

My analyzer is a Analyzer wrapper which is a LowerCase and WhiteSpace analyzer, similar to the built in ones. I do searches with the classic query parser. Searches on exact terms work fine.

What I want to be able to do is this:

query: "version:[1.0-RC1 TO 1.5]" - list all document matching versions between and including the two values

and

psuedoquery: "someField:value AND version:latest" - list all document with someField = value having the latest version

What I tried to do is to convert my version string to an int before indexing, but the query input needs to be converted somehow, so that version string becomes and int before searching.I also experimented with IntPoint with three dimensions but came nowhere with it.

It looks like I have to implement a custom analyzer for the version field, but I'm having problems finding similar examples.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned Lucene version so I assume latest ( >= 6.0.0 ).

[TermRangeQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TermRangeQuery.html) seems a suitable fit for your need but I have not used this class in past.

I have written below sample program to test and it seems to give me desired result. Please include desired lucene jars when using below code.

```
package lucene.productversion;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.SimpleAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field.Store;
import org.apache.lucene.document.StringField;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TermRangeQuery;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;


public class App 
{
    private static String versionField = "version";

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
        App app = new App();

        System.out.println( "Staring Product Version!" );

        File indexDir = new File("D:\\experiments");
        FSDirectory directory = FSDirectory.open(indexDir.toPath());

        Analyzer analyzer = new SimpleAnalyzer();

        app.index(analyzer, directory);

        app.search(analyzer, directory);

        System.out.println( "End Product Version!" );

    }

    private void search(Analyzer analyzer,FSDirectory directory) throws IOException{

        IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

        Query query =  TermRangeQuery.newStringRange(versionField, "1.0", "2.1-RC2", true, true);

        TopDocs topDocs  = searcher.search(query, 10);


        if(topDocs.totalHits <= 0 ){
            System.out.println("No Hits Found");
            return;
        }

        for(ScoreDoc doc:topDocs.scoreDocs){
            System.out.println("Doc Id :"+doc.doc+" Version Number :"+searcher.doc(doc.doc).get(versionField));
        }

        reader.close();

        System.out.println("Searching Completed");
    }

    private void index(Analyzer analyzer,FSDirectory directory) throws IOException{

        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);

        config.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE);

        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, config);


        for(String version:versions()){
            Document doc = new Document();

            doc.add(new StringField(versionField,version,Store.YES));

            writer.addDocument(doc);

        }

        writer.commit();
        writer.close();

        System.out.println("Indexing Completed");
    }

    private List<String> versions(){

        List<String> versions = new ArrayList<>();

        versions.add("1.0");
        versions.add("1.0-RC1");
        versions.add("1.1");
        versions.add("1.2");
        versions.add("2.1-RC1");
        versions.add("2.1-RC2");
        versions.add("2.1-RC3");
        versions.add("3.1-RC1");
        versions.add("3.1");

        return versions;
    }
}
```